# how to iterate over a list of arguments in scrapy spider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, rest

Hi, I'm trying to pass a list of arguments in scrapy spider command. I am able to run it for 1 argument. but unable to do it for a list of arguments. Please help. here what I tried.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json


class AirbnbweatherSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'airbnbweather'
    allowed_domains = ['www.wunderground.com']

    def __init__(self,geocode ):
        self.geocode = geocode.split(',') 
        pass   
       
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/10day?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&geocode={0}{1}{2}&units=e&language=en-US&format=json".format(self.geocode[0],"%2C",self.geocode[1]))

    def parse(self, response):
        resuturant = json.loads(response.body)
        
        yield {
            'temperatureMax' : resuturant.get('temperatureMax'),
            'temperatureMin' : resuturant.get('temperatureMin'),
            'validTimeLocal' : resuturant.get('validTimeLocal'),
            
            }
```

I'm able to run it using this command

```
scrapy crawl airbnbweather -o BOSTON.json -a geocode="42.361","-71.057"
```

it's working fine. but how I I can iterate over a list for geocodes ?

```
list = [("42.361","-71.057"),("29.384","-94.903"),("30.384", "-84.903")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use string as spider arguments (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments), so you should pass the list as a string, and do the parsing in your code.
The following seems to do the trick:

```
import scrapy
import json
import ast


class AirbnbweatherSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'airbnbweather'
    allowed_domains = ['www.wunderground.com']

    def __init__(self, geocode, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geocodes = ast.literal_eval(geocode)

    def start_requests(self):
        for geocode in self.geocodes:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/10day?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&geocode={0}{1}{2}&units=e&language=en-US&format=json".format(geocode[0],"%2C",geocode[1]))
```

You can then run the crawler like this:

```
scrapy crawl airbnbweather -o BOSTON.json -a geocodes='[("42.361","-71.057"),("29.384","-94.903"),("30.384", "-84.903")]'
```